# Best approach to deal with JSON responses in the Front End/Angular when subscribing it as a forkJoin?

Tags: json, angular, interface, fork-join

I have read multiple answers to these kind of issues, and each answer has its own response; 
In my case I am not getting any of those as my interfaces simply don't map the json like I want it to. I have tried multiple solutions, since working with Root-object and nested interfaces, but here I am, asking which is the best approach to deal with these kind of JSON objects in the front end, how to map it this particular one (a fork-Join). and I wanted to ask what are the real benefits of using the interfaces/classes/ maps besides the Intellisense? It has to do with data propagation?

The json structure in question:

```
{
    Title: "", 
    Year: "", 
    Rated: "", 
    Released: "", 
    Runtime: "", 

…}
```

Simple as it is. But back in my service I call it with a forkjoin:

```
 getMovies(name: string, year?: string): Observable<any> {
    let shortPlot = this.http.get(
      "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" +
        name +
        "&plot=short&y=" +
        year +
        "&apikey=[my key]"
    );
    let fullPlot = this.http.get(
      "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + name + "&plot=full&apikey=[my key]"
    );
    return forkJoin([shortPlot, fullPlot]);
  }
```

The subscription in the component:

```
getMovie() {
    this.spinner = true;

     this.movieService
      .getMovies(this.name.value)
      .subscribe((dataList: any) => {
        this.movies = Array.of(dataList[0]);
        this.spinner = false;
        let error: any = this.movies.map(error => error.Error);
        if (error[0]) {
          this.notfound = error[0];
          this.error = true;
        } else {
          this.error = false;
          this.movieRate = this.movies.map(rating => rating.imdbRating.toString());
        }
      })),
      error => console.log(error);
  }
```

And in the HTML I render the data like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let m of movies">

<h5 class="mt-0">{{m.Title}}, {{m.Year}}</h5>
</div>
```

So as you can see I am not working with an interface and I should. Anyone can sort me out?

Thank you

EDIT: the log after subscribe:

[image]

Comment: can you post value returned by `forkJoin([shortPlot, fullPlot]);` after subscribe?

Comment: @Plochie I've edited with a snapshot of the log

Comment: @Plochie, have you seen my edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's break it down,

> what are the real benefits of using the interfaces/classes/ maps besides the Intellisense?

Using interfaces and classes will not just give you intellisense but will also provide static type safety for your code. Why this is important, let's say you have a interface with following structure,

```js
export interface Demo {
   field: string;
}

// in some other file 1
demo.field.substring(1, 2);

// in some other file 2
demo.field.lenght;
```

You are using this interface in many places in your code. Now, for some reason you get to know that the property should be `number` not `string`. So here typescript will give you all the errors at compile time only.

```js
export interface Demo {
   field: number;
}

// in some other file 1
demo.field.substring(1, 2); // error

// in some other file 2
demo.field.lenght // error
```

Also, after `typescript` transpiles it will generate `javascript` files, now as `javascript` is interpreted language, your code will not be tested until the `javascript` run-time actually executes the problematic line, but in typescript you will get errors in compilation stage only.

You can get away with using `any` everywhere, but with that you will be **missing the static typings**.

With interfaces and classes, you **also get OOP features**, such as inheritance etc.

> It has to do with data propagation?

Your frond-end is never aware what type of data will be received from `api`. So it's developers responsibility that the received data should be mapped to some interface.

Again as mentioned above, if somehow back-end changes type of some field in received `json`, then it will again be caught in compile time.

In case of `forkJoin` which combines output of two `json`s you can have two different types.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bi6q82?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
export interface Demo1 {
  field1: string;
}

export interface Demo2 {
  field2: number;
}

// in service layer
getData(): Observable<[Demo1, Demo2]> {
   const res1 = this.http.get(...);
   const res2 = this.http.get(...);
   return forkJoin([res1, res2]);
}

// in component
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(res => {
    // you will get type safety and intellisense for res here
    console.log(res[0].field1)
})
```

> I am not working with an interface and I should.

Yes, you should use `interfaces`, if you are not using using features of `typescript` then whats the point using it. :)

Comment: great answer @Plochie, thank you (im sorry for the delay)

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful.

Comment: im sorry @Plochie, but even following your instructions I get the log undefined if i put it like this: `this.movieService.getMovies('Robocop').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res[0].title)
      
    });` But if i log it like this: `this.movieService.getMovies('Robocop').subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res[0]['Title'])
      
    });` I get the correct log...I've implemented the service as you suggested, but still...

Comment: and also the only difference between the interface and response is that in the interface i dont have camel case

Comment: The field name should exactly be same as key, so res[0].Title should work.

Comment: so this means i have to change the interface to camel case?

Comment: Yes, either that, or you can map incoming json to interface using rxjs map operator.

Comment: yes, it does work! so this means that the interfaces have respect the case sensitive?

Comment: I hope I answered in upper comment.